# content of variables is not showing xcode debugger

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

I have tried to debug something in my application.I run the app by setting the breakpoint, but the debugger showed me the variables without any content.

Here is an image of what I am talking about, I don't understand why the blue arrow does not appear in the left for each of the variables:
[image]

I have also opened another project and when i debugged that one, it worked. Is it related to the settings in xcode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem related to use of Objective-C code in swift projects

Check your `Bridging-Header.h`and remove all unnecessary headers files from there, check if you are using cocoa-pods you need import all your pods with the `import` sentence, never include the header of that pod in your `Bridging-Header.h`

I hope this helps you, I just resolve this problem with this method

Comment: Can you also up vote my answer if don't bother you? @vladmihai

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running a debug build, not a release build. Release builds use code optimizations that get rid of temporary variables, map variables to registers, interleave the code from multiple lines together so you can't cleanly step through line by line, etc.

Comment: I checked. It seems that the problem is not from there.